# Google+ authentication throws SSL error

Tags: php, ssl, google-plus

I have implemented google+ authentication in my php application(I have followed the steps mentioned in https://www.codexworld.com/downloads/login-with-google-api-using-php/) and it was working fine till last week.

But I am getting the error below now and no changes done in the login page (no SSL being used by my app).

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_IOException' with message
    'HTTP Error: (0) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed'
in C:\xampplite\htdocs\UPDATES_login\src\io\Google_CurlIO.php:123
Stack trace:
    #0 C:\xampplite\htdocs\UPDATES_login\src\io\Google_REST.php(35): Google_CurlIO->makeRequest(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
    #1 C:\xampplite\htdocs\UPDATES_login\src\service\Google_ServiceResource.php(186): Google_REST::execute(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
    #2 C:\xampplite\htdocs\UPDATES_login\src\contrib\Google_Oauth2Service.php(36): Google_ServiceResource->__call('get', Array)
    #3 C:\xampplite\htdocs\UPDATES_login\login.php(95): Google_UserinfoServiceResource->get()
    #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampplite\htdocs\UPDATES_login\src\io\Google_CurlIO.php on line 123
```

Can anyone help resolve this?

Comment: http://budiirawan.com/solution-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-verify-ca-cert-ok/

Comment: Thank you for the steps. I have tried it but still no luck :(

Comment: same problem here